# Why Notes app use a lot of resource/energy?

Tags: macos, notes.app, power-management

I use macOS Big Sur on my MacBook Pro early 2015.

Usually, I very rarely open the Notes app, I just using it for copy-paste only,  maybe 4-10 times or 2-5 minutes in  every 12 hours, but usually I leave the app running in the background. When running, even though I haven't opened the application for a long time, CPU and Energy usage is very high compared to other applications that I almost always open and actively use such as Browsers and IDEs.

here is my activity monitor that show energy impact of the Notes app:

[image]

here is CPU usage:

[image]
I have about 1000 notes in that app, is that normal or maybe something is wrong with my Mac?

I don't know when this behavior started, but as I remember it was a long time ago. I always hoped it would be fixed in an OS update, but this happening continues to this day even though there have been several updates. Is this happening only on my MacBook or is someone experiencing the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an [Apple communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252262861) I found this:

> Jan 11, 2021 12:58 PM in response to madmac88
>
> After chatting with Apple support - the problem seems to be related to one (or both) of the 2 non-iCloud accounts that I have set up for Notes. After disabling Notes sync, Notes is now no longer hogging energy!!

It seems to have worked so far, I did have an additional 2 accounts with notes being synced.  I have unchecked the sync and at the moment the notes app does not seem to being consuming the energy it was.  I will continue to test and will update again.

Comment: I only have one account, so I'm still at a loss...